# Reflect the specific of meta sites on meta site’s top banner

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, wording, anonymous-visitors

I take an Academia site for an example, but almost any other site is affected. To check the issue just open sites in browser private mode.

I noticed that top banner of main and meta sites are the same except of site names:

- [main](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)

  > [image: main]
- [meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/)

  > [image: meta]

But the right banner for meta says that site is used for **discussion** of main site. I suggest to reflect this specific in the top banner too:

> [image: reflect meta nature]

In particular it possibly can prevent (or at least reduce) posting a question on meta sites instead of main for some newbies than already has 5+ rep to participate on meta. I’ve seen small amount of post on ruSO.meta which should be questioned on main sites instead. And think that same behavior can exists on any SE site.