# Why do users downvote duplicates, but not origins?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, duplicate-questions

I seen it several times before, but still can’t clearly understand: why do user downvote posts which a closed as duplicates, and on the same time don’t downvote origin posts?

Do they want to drop duplicates for roomba-cleaner when post gets a lot of downvotes, or something else? As far as I know the duplicates are not bad, because they help to find same things by different words. So if the user is disagree with duplicate post, he should disagree with the origin one, ain’t it?

Comment: Not necessarily. A user may find that the required "research effort" is not met when asking duplicate questions. And that's a valid downvote reason.

Comment: By looking at score I think this question definitely has a duplicate!

Comment: @älёxölüt I think it's the other reason: lack of research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the duplicates you've seen were probably of low quality and had little or no value to the community as they were.

But this is definitely not the case solely because they were duplicates. On the contrary, I've seen many duplicates get **upvotes**. Maybe they've used sufficiently different keywords and shown their research and so despite being a duplicate, their question will be valuable to the community for redirecting others who may not have found the original themselves. (Here are a few SO C++ examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8522055/2602718), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45898184/2602718), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5060137/2602718)).

Remember that SE tends to be fairly objective with content. Most of the time we don't look at the user or how difficult the subject matter is. What we care about is whether or not the question will bring our community closer to being an all-encompassing repository of well-written, thoughtful problems and solutions.

Answer (score 15):

Quoting the downvote tooltip:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

When googling the title of a question or the error message in the question immediately turns up a duplicate, that demonstrates a clear lack of research effort. It is easy to determine this for duplicates and hard to determine this for originals, since it's hard to tell what Google would have turned up when the original question was posted.

Comment: For instance, I recently [asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321398/reflect-the-specific-of-meta-sites-on-meta-site-s-top-banner) via SE app, and there is [no duplicate in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtbC6.jpg). Should I leave the app to google for duplicate if the app don’t show me the duplicate?

Comment: @älёxölüt Do you think that people with that question's problem doing reasonable research efforts to solve that problem are likely to find your question and not the canonical?  If yes, your question is useful as it's improving the visibility of the canonical.  If not, then it's not useful.  Sometimes the same fundamental question can be asked in such a radically different way from other versions of the same question that people will find one and not the others.  Those duplicates are useful.  But other duplicates are just repeating what's in the canonical and are no more discoverable than it.

Answer (score 10):

It's because some duplicates appear to lack any research effort. That's what downvoting is for: content that lacks research effort. Very easy-to-find duplicates tend to get downvoted. However, not all duplicates get downvoted. I have a couple of positively-scored duplicate questions.

Comment: I'm not saying about totally downvoted duplicates. Please look at my comment on another answer. The duplicate has positive score, but also a downvote, when the origin doesn't.

Comment: @älёxölüt then one user thought it wasn't useful. If it has positive score, the community in general agrees it's useful, but it's rare to have a question with no downvotes at all.